# i cannot access python selenium chromedriver form jupiter Notebook

Tags: list, selenium, jupyter-notebook, selenium-chromedriver, undetected-chromedriver

```
pip install selenium
```

**After installing selenium in jupiter
i have download chromedriver and saved it to C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chromedriver.exe**

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://instagram.com")
```

**I am getting error like please help to use chromedriver using jupiter notebook any help will be appreciated

Even i have add Root path, r string, nothing worked**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
    /srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py in start(self)
         75                                             stderr=self.log_file,
    ---> 76                                             stdin=PIPE)
         77         except TypeError:
    
    /srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py in __init__(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, restore_signals, start_new_session, pass_fds, encoding, errors)
        728                                 errread, errwrite,
    --> 729                                 restore_signals, start_new_session)
        730         except:

/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py in _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite, restore_signals, start_new_session)
   1363                             err_msg += ': ' + repr(err_filename)
-> 1364                     raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
   1365                 raise child_exception_type(err_msg)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chromedriver.exe': 'C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chromedriver.exe'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

WebDriverException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-924a85514f82> in <module>
      1 from selenium import webdriver
----> 2 driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chromedriver.exe")
      3 driver.get("https://instagram.com")

/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py in __init__(self, executable_path, port, options, service_args, desired_capabilities, service_log_path, chrome_options, keep_alive)
     71             service_args=service_args,
     72             log_path=service_log_path)
---> 73         self.service.start()
     74 
     75         try:

/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py in start(self)
     81                 raise WebDriverException(
     82                     "'%s' executable needs to be in PATH. %s" % (
---> 83                         os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
     84                 )
     85             elif err.errno == errno.EACCES:

WebDriverException: Message: 'C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```